# How to session to display data in other page

Tags: asp.net, session

I  have some text boxes. Users are required to key in data in the text boxes. When they finished, they will click on submit button. Then, it will be directed to "review.aspx" page. In the review.aspx page, the page will display the data inserted by them in previous page in label. Anyone here knows how to do it? Thanks.

This is where I stop

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["brand"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    Session["model"] = TextBox1.Text;
    Session["plate"] = TextBox2.Text;
    Session["color"] = TextBox3.Text;
    Session["year"] = TextBox4.Text;
    Session["service"] = TextBox5.Text;

    Response.Redirect "Review.aspx";
```

How to catch the session to be displayed in review page. I used label to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the session["ID"] object to string in following way:

```
    string brand=Session["brand"].ToString();
    string model=Session["model"].ToString(); 
    string plate=Session["plate"].ToString();
    string color=Session["color"].ToString();
    string year=Session["year"].ToString();
    string service=Session["service"].ToString();
```

and Set the value in respective label:

```
lblBrand.Text=brand;
lblModel.Text=model;
lblPlate.Text=plate;
lblColor.Text=color;
lblYear.Text=year;
lblService.Text=service;
```

Answer (score 1):

Session datatype is object, we have to cast it to String type so that we can store it in a string variable.

```
string brand =    Session["brand"].ToString();
string  model =(string) Session["model"];
string  plate =(string)  Session["plate"];
string  color =(string)  Session["color"];
string  year =(string)  Session["year"];
string  service =(string)  Session["service"];
```

set your label text property equal to these variables

```
Label1.Text = brand+""+model+""+plate+""+year+""+service;
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to display data on the other page using session(Sample for beginners)**

step1:Take two webforms webform1 & webform2.

step2:Drag a texbox & a button on webform1 & write the following code in the button click event-

```
Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text;

Response.Redirect("webform2.aspx");
```

step3:drag a label on webform2 & write the following code in the page load event of this page (ie:webform2).

```
Label1.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
```

Conclusion:The name/data entered into the textbox on webform1 will be displayed on the next page.